# Android programming onCreate Method

Tags: android, android-intent

I Have been working on this program as an assignment and this question I have been trying to answer and to me it should be just:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
```

But it is incorrect!
The code below and the question below is what leads me to this answer.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
  }
```

I need to fetch that `Intent` object that this class will receive from `HelloWorldActivity`.
So,

Declare a new variable of type Bundle named data, and assign it the value of calling `getIntent().getExtras()` from this class.

So I have seached and searched for the answer I do not understand .

again I answered :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and it is incorrect. Could someone explain to me what I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that the incoming Intent that started your Activity contains a Bundle in its extended data. That is, HelloWorldActivity has to have done the following:

Intent sendIntent = newIntent(this, HelloWorld.class); 
// or some other way of pointing the Intent to the right Activity
Bundle sendBundle = new Bundle();
// Some examples of putting data into the Bundle
// Notice that keys should use a package prefix.
sendBundle.putString("com.example.android.myapp.HELLOWORLD_KEY","Hello, World");
// etc.
sendIntent.putExtras(sendBundle);
startActivity(sendIntent);

If you do this, then in HelloWorld you can call

Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

which will return what you put into sendBundle.

I usually add an action to an outgoing Intent, even if I use an explicit Intent. That allows me to check an incoming Intent somewhere else for the right action. I also test that the extended data in the Intent isn't null before I try to do something with it.

Finally, remember that the statement

Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

should be in onCreate();